# Trying to spawn ruby sass from Node

Tags: node.js, sass, npm, exec, spawn

I have script called sassy.js

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    rubySass = spawn('sass', ['--watch scss:.tmp/css', '--sourcemap=auto', '--style=expanded', '--unix-newlines']);
```

which I try to run with node sassy.js

```
$ node sassy.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn sass ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

It's strange because this code works:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    rubySass = exec('sass --watch scss:.tmp/css --sourcemap=auto --style=expanded --unix-newlines');
```

I choose spawn beacuse finally I want to return stdout which I could redirect to node package called clean-css by Npm run script

```
"scripts": {
    "build-sass:clean": "node sassy.js | 
}
```

with: `npm run build-sass:clean`

**EDITED**

After help from [Lovell Fuller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4625124/lovell-fuller) I updated sassy.js `rubySass = spawn('c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/sass', ['--watch scss:.tmp/css', '--sourcemap=auto', '--style=expanded', '--unix-newlines'])`

but `node sassy.js` stills yelds

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/sass ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I've tried with `c:/Ruby21-x64/bin/sass.bat`but despite no errors, there is no output as well :-/

Comment: Including the `.bat` suffix is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` uses the shell to run commands and is able to locate and prefix `sass` with its full path.

`spawn` does not run commands via the shell so you'll need to provide the full path, e.g. `/usr/bin/sass`.

If you're unsure what the full path needs to be, the `which sass` command should provide this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be relevant but did you forget a end quotation?

```
 "scripts": {
     "build-sass:clean": (--->)"node sassy.js | 
 }


"scripts": {
     "build-sass:clean": "node sassy.js" | 
 }
```